# Imagick exists, but PHP says it is not found

Tags: php, imagick

I am using php version 7.4.4 with Windows x64 Architecture and tried to installed imagick. So I downloaded "php_imagick-3.4.4-7.4-ts-vc15-x64" and unzipped it and put it in the ext-folder. When I tried to execute PHP Info it however said it doesn´t find the dll. So I checked, where it is searching for it and it was: "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_imagick.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll (Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_imagick.dll.dll (Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.)) in Unknown on line 0" I also checked the extension_dir, which is: "extension_dir => C:\xampp\php\ext => C:\xampp\php\ext"

I checked the path of my dll, to make sure, I am not just dumb and copied above path used inside my file-explorer, since my windows warned me that I am about to execute a dll, which proves that it exists.
This also can be seen in below screenshot.
Am I missing something important?
[image]

Comment: follow this instruction: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/349/how-to-install-and-enable-the-imagick-extension-in-xampp-for-windows

Comment: Did you enable the extension in your PHP config?

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was missing to add the path to the remaining binaries to the PATH variable.
So you need to go into your system variables, choose the variable "PATH", edit it and add another path. Since I was using xampp in my case it was apache/bin.